# Getting no results while parsing data from a php site through PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php

I have been trying to get names of all inputs from such a page which needs to get login at first and then that is view able but it's not giving me any results as..!

```
<?php
  include('simple_html_dom.php');
  $html = file_get_html('http://www.infamousgangsters.com/site.php?page=kill');
  foreach($html->find('input') as $element) 
  echo $element->name . '<br>';
?>
```

Here if you people want to confirm the page has input fields here is screenshot as please : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lW9H.png

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` We'll wait for your update.

Comment: still showing nothing after adding error_reporting. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the right link page? because that one doesn't have any input

Comment: Sure...it has inputs...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to login. Which means you need to send the right cookies in your `file_get_html` request. But since Simple HTML DOM does support that you will need to use `get_file_contents` with a `context`. But it would probably be easier to use [`cURL` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).

Comment: And how am I suppose to do that?

Comment: That is a much more complicated question. Look for a guide, but here is one to get you started. http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Comment: I logged in through CURL but sitll the HTML DOM Parser is not working..!

Comment: What HTML are you getting back after logging in? Really, this is pretty basic debugging.

Comment: Thanks that's fixed now..!